# SQL select statement to a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a parameter, that contains a comma separated list columns, so I can use this dynamically later on. However i'm having an issue writing my select query, into a parameter that can be used to a separate select.

This is my parameter, to define the comma seperated list;

```
DECLARE @sqlSrcCols VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlSrcCols = '
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  '','' + a.sourceName
        FROM #matchedFields a
    FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''') AS listStr'
```

This outputs a comma seperated list like so;

abc,cde,dfg,thy

I want to then reference that list, in a query like below:

```
DECLARE @sqlSelect VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @sqlSrcCols + 'FROM a.TableName WHERE ExpDat = ''2020-01-01'' '
EXEC(@sqlSelect)
```

Although I can't use @sqlSrcCols within my query, and I can't use EXEC(@sqlSrcCols).

Any help welcomed.

Comment: Your code looks fine although the column names might need to be quoted.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "`... @sqlSrcCols + 'FROM ...`" -- There's probably a space missing between the last column and `FROM`.

Comment: May be some space in @sqlSrcCols variable, select that variable and verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, but I think what you *actually* mean to do is:

```
DECLARE @sqlSrcCols nvarchar(MAX); --Fixed datatype
SET @sqlSrcCols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(mF.sourceName) --Quoting is important
                         FROM #matchedFields mF --"a" for matchedFields?
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,''); --used TYPE, in case of any odd characters


DECLARE @sqlSelect nvarchar(MAX);
SET @sqlSelect = N'SELECT ' + @sqlSrcCols + N' FROM a.TableName WHERE ExpDat = ''20200101'';'; --ISO dates are better, they won't fail depending on language/data type
--PRINT @SQL; --You debugging friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; --Don't use EXEC(@SQL), use sp_executesql so you can parametrise when needed.
```

You weren't setting the value of `@sqlSrcCols` to be the names of the columns, you were setting it to the SQL statement. Then, when you concatenated the 2 variables, you ended up with a statement that would have looked like this:

```
SELECT 
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + a.sourceName
        FROM #matchedFields a
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStrFROM a.TableName WHERE ExpDat = '2020-01-01'
```

Which, as you can see, doesn't make any sense.

*Bonus: I would actually write the above like you see below. The reason being is that then you have formatting in your dynamic SQL too; making it easier to debug. I have also parametrised `@ExpDat`, incase it needs to be (and this therefore shows you have to parametrise a dynamic statement):*

```
DECLARE @sqlSrcCols nvarchar(MAX), --Fixed datatype
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);


SET @sqlSrcCols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                                N'       ' + QUOTENAME(mF.sourceName) --Quoting is important
                         FROM #matchedFields mF --"a" for matchedFields?
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,N''); --used TYPE, in case of any odd characters


DECLARE @sqlSelect nvarchar(MAX);
SET @sqlSelect = N'SELECT ' + @sqlSrcCols + @CRLF +
                 N'FROM a.TableName' + @CRLF +
                 N'WHERE ExpDat = @ExpDat;'; --ISO dates are better, they won't fail depending on language/data type
--PRINT @SQL; --You debugging friend
DECLARE @ExpDat date = '20200101';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ExpDat date', @ExpDat; --Don't use EXEC(@SQL), use sp_executesql so you can parametrise when needed.
```

*If you're interested, you can find some of pointers on Dynamic SQL, what to do and not to do, in my article on [SSC](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).*

Comment: Larnu, thanks for your detailed response, that's very useful and i've had a look at your article, makes much more sense.

I have just tried running the code you provided, but I get an error;

Must declare the scalar variable "@ExpDat". 

Also, I assume it should be EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlSelect

Comment: Fixed, @dawsonz . I can't test the above, I don't have your tables, so there was a typographical error there.